# Is String.trim() faster than String.replace()?

Tags: java

Let's say there has a string like `" world "`. This String only has the blank at front and end. Is the `trim()` faster than `replace()`?

I used the replace once and my mentor said don't use it since the `trim()` probably faster.

If not, what's the advantage of `trim()` than `replace()`?

Comment: Well, they work differently.  `trim` works only at the beginning and end and `replace` will replace characters in the middle of a string too.

Comment: Yes, I mean based on the string like `" work "`, it only has blanks at the front and end

Comment: This is very implementation dependent.

Comment: It might be more productive to ask your mentor to explain the specific reasons they said to use trim than posting here...

Comment: @MadPhysicist He did explain. And he's probably right.

Comment: Also, I would make the same recommendation as your mentor, but not because of speed. It's that replace is more dangerous since one day you will get that string with spaces not just around the ends.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why not? Would "it's definitely faster" be preferable?

Comment: @shmosel. An explanation of why would be preferable.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It seems pretty self-explanatory, at least in the general case.

Comment: *If not, what's the advantage of trim() than replace()?* They do different things and convey different intents. I don't really get the question.

Comment: @Meilan it's probably more constructive to take a look at the source code of the `String` class, the 2 methods are pretty small and easy to understand. You could copy the code and test removing the first/last spaces on your own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2141) for the methods:

[`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
 public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    String tgtStr = target.toString();
    String replStr = replacement.toString();
    int j = indexOf(tgtStr);
    if (j < 0) {
        return this;
    }
    int tgtLen = tgtStr.length();
    int tgtLen1 = Math.max(tgtLen, 1);
    int thisLen = length();
    int newLenHint = thisLen - tgtLen + replStr.length();
    if (newLenHint < 0) {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(newLenHint);
    int i = 0;
    do {
        sb.append(this, i, j).append(replStr);
        i = j + tgtLen;
    } while (j < thisLen && (j = indexOf(tgtStr, j + tgtLen1)) > 0);
    return sb.append(this, i, thisLen).toString()
}
```

Vs [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()):

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */
    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

As you can see `replace()` calls multiple other methods and iterates throughout the entire `String`, while `trim()` simply iterates over the beginning and ending of the `String` until the character isn't a white space. So in the single respect of trying to ***only*** remove white space before and after a word, `trim()` is more efficient.

---

We can run some benchmarks on this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       long testStartTime = System.nanoTime();;
       trimTest();
       long trimTestTime = System.nanoTime() - testStartTime;
       testStartTime = System.nanoTime();     
       replaceTest();
       long replaceTime = System.nanoTime() - testStartTime;           
       System.out.println("Time for trim(): " + trimTestTime);
       System.out.println("Time for replace(): " + replaceTime);            
}

public static void trimTest() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {     
        new String("  string   ").trim();
    }
}
public static void replaceTest() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {     
        new String("  string   ").replace(" ", "");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Time for trim(): 53303903
Time for replace(): 485536597
//432,232,694 difference
```

Comment: I would have suspected something like this, but the number of calls in `replace` is really quite a bit bigger than I would have expected.  Still, this is implementation dependent.  The rule I think is to use `trim` where it will work and use `replace` in situations where it's needed.  Only optimize when a profiler running real code says that a section needs to be optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the people writing the Java library code are doing a good job<sup>1</sup>, you can assume that a special purpose method (like `trim()`) will be as fast, and probably faster than a general purpose method (like `replace(...)`) doing the same thing.

Two reasons:

- If the special purpose method is slower, its implementation can be rewritten as equivalent calls to the general purpose one, making the performance equivalent in most cases.  A competent programmer will do this because it reduces maintenance costs.
- In the special purpose method, it is likely that there will be optimizations that can be made that don't apply in the general-purpose case.

In this case we know that `trim()` only *needs* to look at the start and end of the string ... whereas `replace(...)` *needs* to look at all of the characters in the string.  (We can infer this from the description of what the respective methods do.)

If we assume "competence" then we can infer that the developers will have done the analysis and not implemented `trim()` sub-optimally<sup>2</sup>; i.e. they won't code `trim()` to examine all characters.

---

There is another reason to use the special purpose method over the general purpose.  It makes your code simpler, easier to read, and easier to inspect for correctness.  This may well be *more important* than performance.

This clearly applies in the case of `trim()` versus `replace(...)`.

---

<sup>1 - We can in this case.  There are lots of eyes looking at this code, and lots of people who will complain loudly about egregious performance issues.</sup>

<sup>2 - Unfortunately, it is not always as straightforward as this.  A library method needs to be optimized for "typical" behavior, but it also needs to avoid pathological performance in edge-cases.  It is not always possible to achieve both things.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`trim()` is definitely faster to type, yes. It doesn't take any parameters.

It is also much faster to understand what you where trying to do. You were trying to *trim* the string, rather than *replacing all the spaces it contains with the empty string, knowing from other context that there is only space at the beginning and the end of the string*.

Indeed much faster no matter how you look at it. Don't complicate the life of the persons who're trying to read your code. Most of the time, it will be you months later, or at least someone you don't hate.

Answer (score 1):

Trim will prune the outter characters until they are non white space.  I believe they trim space, tab, and new lines.

Replace will scan the entire string (so, it could be a sentense) and would replace inner " " with "", essentially compressing them together.

They have different use cases though, obviously 1 is to clean up user input where the other is to update a string where matches are found with something else.

That being said, run times:  Replace will run in N time, as it will look for all matching characters.  Trim will run in O(N), but most likely a just a few characters off of each end.

The idea behind trim i think came around from people would would type and input things but accidentally press space before submitting their forms, essentially trying to save the field "Foo " instead of "Foo"

Answer (score 0):

`s.trim()` shortens a `String s`. This means no characters has to be moved from an index to another. It starts at the first character (`s.toCharArray()[0]`) of the `String` and shortens the `String` character by character until the first non-whitespace character occurs. It works the same way to shorten the `String` at the end. So it compresses the `String`. If a `String` has no leading and trailing whitespace `trim` will be ready after checking the first and the last character.

In case of `" world ".trim()` two steps are needed: one to remove the first leading whitespace as it is on the first index and the the second to remove the last whitespace as it is on the last index.

`" world ".replace(" ", "")` will need at least `n = " world ".length()` steps. It has to check every character if it has to be replaced. But if we take into account that the implementation of `String.replace(...)` needs to compile a `Pattern`, build a `Matcher` and then to replace all the matched regions it's seems far complex comparing to shorten a `String`.

We also have to consider that `" world ".replace(" ", "")` does not replace whitespaces but only the `String` `" "`. Since `String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` compiles the target using `Pattern.LITERAL` we cannot use the character class *\s*. To be more accurate we would have to compare `" world ".trim()` to `" world ".replaceAll("\\s", "")`. It is still not the same because a whitespace in `String trim()` is defined as `c <= ' '` for each `c` in `s.toCharArray()`.

Summarizing: `String.trim()` should be faster - especially for long strings

The description how the methods work is based on the implementation of `String` in Java 8. But implementations can change.

But the question should be: What do you intent to do with the string? Do you want to trim it or to replace some characters? According to it use the corresponding method.